# error SQLSTATE[HY093] when trying to edit database via webapp

Tags: php, sql, pdo

When I try to edit the database, I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

There are questions related to this error, but they don't seem to apply to this case. Thanks!!

```
<php
 ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
 ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(-1);

    require_once 'db.php';  
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       $get_id=$_REQUEST['id'];   
       $name=$_POST['name'];
       $surname=$_POST['surname'];
       $pic = $_FILES['pic']['name'];

        try{           
            move_uploaded_file($pic,"uploads/$pic");
            $stmt = $db_con->prepare("UPDATE posts SET
            name=:name,surname=:surname,pic=:pic WHERE id=:GET_id");

            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
            $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
            $stmt->bindParam(":surname", $surname);
            $stmt->bindParam(":pic", $pic);

                 if($pic=="")    {
                                  move_uploaded_file($pic,"uploads/$pic");
                                  ("UPDATE posts SET name=:name, surname=:surname, pic=:pic WHERE id=:GET_id");

            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
            $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
            $stmt->bindParam(":surname", $surname);
            $stmt->bindParam(":pic", $pic);
    }
         if($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Successfully Updated!!!'); window.location='index.php'</script>";
        }
        else{
            echo "Query Problem";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `GET_id` to `id` in both query

```
WHERE id=:id
```

and also here change `$get_id` to `$id` as you used `$id` in below code

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```